# R: change tolerance limits in GenSA

Tags: r, optimization, parameter-passing, nonlinear-optimization, convergence

I am trying to solve an optimization problem and using the package `GenSA`. I was looking for the tolerance limit defining parameters in this function but seems like that cannot be defined.

I want the optimization to stop if the value of the objective function does not change in 2 steps by an amount of 1000 units. Other functions like `nloptr` and `rgenoud` allow such tolerance limits to be passed as arguments, but I fail to find such argument in this function.

I noticed that `GenSA` uses `constrOptim` inside it and I tried to change the argument *outer.eps*, but that did not help serve the purpose.

Could someone suggest what can be done here?